# how can i get the value of a td

Tags: javascript, html-table, spiceworks

i want to get the value of this [td](http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/2028/olasd.png)

my code

```
 function check() {
     var e = document.getElementById("ticket_category_clone");
     var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

     alert(str);
     if (str === "Hardware") {
         SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle('#ticket_c_hardware_clone{display: none !important;}');
     }

 }

 SPICEWORKS.app.helpdesk.ready(check);
```

and bang it does Nothing, what could be the problem?

the html srry for not post it in the begging

```
 <select id="ticket_category_clone" name="ticket[category]" hdpp="ticket_category">
    <option value=""></option><option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
    <option value="Software">Software</option>
    <option value="Rede" selected="selected">Rede</option>
    <option value="Pedidos">Pedidos</option>
    <option value="Formação/Dúvida">Formação/Dúvida</option>
    <option value="Outro">Outro</option><option value="#edit_categories#">Edit Categories...</option></select>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Well whatever it looks like, if you're fetching a `<td>` it's pretty curious to expect it to have an "options" property. Are you sure you're not looking for a `<select>` element?

Comment: oh srry i forgot to post the img

Comment: @Pointy just posted the img now

Comment: OK, well **(1)** you can't use `.getElementById()` the way you're using it, and **(2)** even if it worked, you're trying to treat the `<td>` element as if it were a `<select>` element, which it clearly is not.

Comment: Well now that you've posted the actual relevant code, it's pretty straightforward. The element you want to get is "ticket_category_clone", not the `<td>`.  Then you can look at the "options" property, etc.

Comment: so i just neeed to change it to ticket_category_clone? see the code

Comment: Just changing it to `ticket_category_clone` won't fix the problem. Please see my answer.

Comment: Yes, because that's the "id" of the `<select>` element.  Now, whether that "addStyles" thing will work or not, I don't know; I'm not familiar with the SpiceWorks code (though I used to work with some SpiceWorks people :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
var e = document.getElementById("td.body-c_hardware.cell-c_hardware");
var str = e.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById), your tag needs an id

```
<table>
  <tr><td id="idValue">Content</td></tr>
</table>
```

and you need to fetch it by just using the id value

```
document.getElementById('idValue');
```

---

If you want to use CSS-like selectors, you may be best using a toolkit like jQuery

```
jQuery('#idValue');
jQuery('td.className');
jQuery('table.tableClass td.cellClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the select element by its id. You can then access either the text of the option or the value of the option. I think you may want the value instead of the text. I have posted a solution for both ways.

http://jsfiddle.net/c4eWg/1

```
var e = document.getElementById('ticket_category_clone');
alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
```

​
If you want the actual value, and not the text then use this instead. I suspect it might be what you want.

```
var e = document.getElementById('ticket_category_clone');
alert(e.value);
```

Comment: it dosent do any thing i think the problem its from spiceworks

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Hope you figure it out.